# Office add-in, turn html image into an insertable image

Tags: office-addins

If I have an image inside the add-in HTML, in what way I can make that image available for used in an Office app itself? Such as, when the user click on the image inside the add-in frame, the same image should be available outside of the add-in frame.

Update: For **Powerpoint** please (I wasn't aware of the inconsistency of the API across Office applications)

Answer (score 0):

If the image is hosted somewhere publicly, you can insert it with the [Range.insertHtml() method](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/word/word-add-ins-javascript-reference/range.md#inserthtmlhtml-string-insertlocation-insertlocation). Alternatively, if the image is constructed dynamically in a base64-encoded file, you can insert it with the [Range.insertFileFromBase64() method](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/word/word-add-ins-javascript-reference/range.md#insertInlinePictureFromBase64base64EncodedImage-string-insertlocation-insertlocation).

If you'd like the add-in to also work in Office 2013, you can [insert images using the Document object](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/10/26/inserting-images-with-apps-for-office/).

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Update: For PowerPoint specifically, the Range object is not available but you can still insert images with the Document object: call [setSelectedDataAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/fp142145(v=office.15)) with the Image coercion type.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that the solution has to work on Powerpoint. Both insertHTML and setSelectedDataAsync don't work for Powerpoint.

Comment: So I can't even do it with inserting base64?

Comment: According to this msdn page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142145.aspx it says "Base64 encoded image stream (Office.CoercionType.Image) - Applies to Excel, PowerPoint, and Word only" so is it possible or impossible to insert an image from an add-in to powerpoint?

Comment: You're correct Andy - image insertion in PPT is achievable with the Document object. I'll update my answer to include that per-application detail.